# How to wait on Task with OnlyOnFaulted option?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have this simple HelloTask WorldTask console program. When HelloTask throw an error, I would like to call ExceptionTask and after that notify user that program ended.

I am able to call ExceptionTask, but I am not able to await the Task. I am getting `TaskCanceledException` or user message is printed before ExceptionTask finished.

How to solve this issue ? Is there a way to wait on ExceptionTask or check if a task was cancelled ?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task helloTask = Task.Run(() => HelloTask());

            var worldTask = helloTask.ContinueWith((prevTask) => WorldTask(), 
                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

            var exceptionTask = helloTask.ContinueWith((prevTask) => ExceptionTask(), 
                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

            // When no error: AggregationException is thrown 
            // with message "TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.".
            // exceptionTask.Wait(); 

            // When error: AggregationException is thrown 
            // with message "TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled."
            // worldTask.Wait();

            // When error: After worldTask is cancelled user message is called, 
            // but that is before exceptionTask is finished !
            //Task.WaitAny(worldTask, exceptionTask); 

            var userMessage = "Finished processing. Press a key to end.";
            Console.WriteLine(userMessage);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void HelloTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // Intentional error.
            var x = 0;
            var y = 1 / x;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }

        static void WorldTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("World");
        }

        static void ExceptionTask()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Exception happened!");
        }
}
```

Comment: One option could be the try/catch approach--wrap the `Task.Run() => HelloTask()` in a try/catch, in the catch block run the exception task.

Comment: As a side note, the method names `HelloTask`, `WorldTask` and `ExceptionTask` are a bit confusing, because these are not asynchronous methods, neither are tasks. The name `HelloTask` could be appropriate for a property of type `Task`: `public Task HelloTask {get; set;}`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: good point, I didnt realize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent` and then await the original task.

e.g.:

```
        Task helloTask = Task.Run(() => HelloTask());

        var worldTask = helloTask.ContinueWith((prevTask) => WorldTask(), 
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        var exceptionTask = helloTask.ContinueWith((prevTask) => ExceptionTask(), 
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);

        await helloTask;
```

Vary as needed depending upon whether you want to wait for the worldTask or not.

Then use a try catch statement and catch the relevant exception (Cancellation or Aggregate) where you're calling it.

Comment: I have `static void Main(string[] args)` so instead of `await helloTask` I try `helloTask.Wait();` and it throws `AggregateException` but before that `ExceptionTask()` is triggered so it seems I have to use `try-catch` anyway.

Comment: Yes, when you wait on a task at the top level you always have to handle the possible exceptions that could be thrown by that task or any of its children.

Comment: Main can be `async` since c# 7 no need for `Wait`

Answer (score 3):

> How to solve this issue ? Is there a way to wait on ExceptionTask or check if a task was cancelled ?

I strongly recommend replacing all instances of `ContinueWith` with `await`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    await Task.Run(() => HelloTask());
    WorldTask();
  }
  catch
  {
    ExceptionTask();
  }

  var userMessage = "Finished processing. Press a key to end.";
  Console.WriteLine(userMessage);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) method as a handler of the "completion event" of the task:

```
Task helloTask = Task.Run(() => Hello());
OnHelloCompletion();

async void OnHelloCompletion()
{
    try
    {
        await helloTask;
        Console.WriteLine("Hello completed successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello failed, {ex}");
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
}
```

The advantages over using the `ContinueWith` method is the increased expressiveness of the code, and the fact that no fire-and-forget `Task` is created. If there is any bug inside the `OnHelloCompletion` method that results to an unexpected exception, you'll learn about it right away since exceptions inside `async void` method cause the immediate crash of the application. Just like unhandled exceptions thrown inside event handlers of UI applications.